# Graph error Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series

Tags: c#, mschart

I want to create a Chart in c# windows form, but I keep getting this error

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series.
> Parameter name: dataSource'

this is my code

```
public void LoadChart()
    {
        Con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Year(sdate) as year, isnull(sum(total),0.0) as total from tblCart where status like 'Sold' group by Year(sdate)",Con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds, "Sales");
        chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Sales"];
        Series series1 = chart1.Series["Series1"];
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;

        series1.Name = "SALES";

        var chart = chart1;
        chart.Series[series1.Name].XValueMember = "year";
        chart.Series[series1.Name].XValueMember = "total";
        chart.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        //chart.DataBind();
        Con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur? And are you intentionally setting `chart.Series[series1.Name].XValueMember` twice?

Comment: A __Pie or doughnut__ chartttype can __only__ have Y- not X-Values. Try to set the YValueMember only. Btw, and not related: Also I recommend not to bind the Chart itself but  the Points of a Series..